# PHP cURL progress_callback

Tags: php, curl, callback

I am trying to use the cURL `progress_callback` function, and I'm having a problem with that.

At the begining the function returns `0` for the "loaded" bytes, and `0` for the "total".
After that it returns a lot of times: total: the size (it's ok), but it says that the "loaded" is also the file size.

For example, I run the script on a file that his size is `10028` bytes. The result:

```
{loaded: 0, total: 0}
{loaded: 10028, total: 10028}
{loaded: 10028, total: 10028}
{loaded: 10028, total: 10028}
```

As you can see, it says "loaded" 10028 and keeps running.
I want it to write the real proccess (for instance: if the file size is `10` bytes, so: 0, 3, 6, 9, 10. And not 0, 10, 10, 10, 10)

The code:

```
$fp = fopen($temp_file, "w");
$ch = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_NOPROGRESS, false );
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROGRESSFUNCTION, "curl_progress_callback");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FILE, $fp);
$success = curl_exec($ch);
$curl_info = curl_getinfo($ch);
curl_close($ch);
fclose($fp);

function curl_progress_callback ($download_size, $downloaded_size, $upload_size, $uploaded_size) {
    global $fileinfo;
    if (!$downloaded_size) {
        if (!isset($fileinfo->size)) {
            $fileinfo->size = $download_size;
            event_callback(array("send" => $fileinfo));
        }
    }
    event_callback(array("progress" => array("loaded" => $downloaded_size, "total" => $download_size)));
}
function event_callback ($message) {
    global $callback;
    echo "<script>parent.".$callback."(".json_encode($message).");</script>";
}
```

Thank you!

Comment: 10028 Bytes is much too small for meaningfull use of the callback ... try with something 1000 times larger!

Comment: @EugenRieck You are right, that was the problem...